# Case insensitive search in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I forced with problem searching by email. Email has **keyword** type. Some users add an email with capital letters, so I can't search all of them via **term** construction. Locally I tried to change **keyword** to **text** but the new problem has appeared. 
Example: search by email@gmail.com - elastic splits this email to several parts and returns wrong results: email@site.com, new@gmail.com and etc.
What is the best way to do this kind of search via elastic? (it would be better to avoid full reindex)

ElasticSearch 6.6.1

```
"mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reindex your index (or add a secondary field with unsensitive case analyzer and query on this field, delete the first field and rename fieldname, but it will be a little more complicated maybe ). Indeed, as if you could add an analyzer by closing and reopening index, elastic have to reindex older data.

For the analyzer a lowercase should be ok in your case.

```
    "analyzer":{
      "analyzer_lowcase":{
        "tokenizer":"keyword",
        "filter":"lowercase"
      }
```

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work `"Mapping definition for [email] has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : analyzer_lowcase]"
`.  So I use `normalizer` instead of. Thx for the hint.